How to add Redis v7 nodes to a cluster withs Redis v6 nodes?
We have a Redis v6 cluster with 27 nodes.
We wanted to gradually upgrade the cluster to Redis v7.
After creating Redis v7 instances, we are unable to join new Redises to our v6 cluster.
After running command redis-cli —cluster add-node command the execution of commands gets stucked at Waiting for cluster to join and multiple dots start getting printed.
All ports and firewalls are ok and cluster bus port is open.
We could join Redis7s together but we can’t join them to the v6 cluster.
My question is that can we upgrade redis nodes one by one or we have to setup a brand-new v7 cluster?
